# debian/rules:161: recipe for target 'config.status' failed

Tags: ubuntu, debian, configure, dpkg

> I had originally posted this few days ago on askubuntu @
>   https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044708/debian-rules161-recipe-for-target-config-status-failed
>
> Unfortunately, I failed to get any responses. Hence looking for some
>   help on StackOverflow.

I am trying to build a `deb` package for `collect-pw`. The upstream tar ball is: 
http://perfwatcher.free.fr/download/collectd/collectd-5.4.0.20150311.tar.gz

For building this package, I pulled the source package for `collectd` from ubuntu repo and modified the package name under `debian/control` and `debian/changelog`.

Now, when I run `pdebuild` (OR `debuild` for that sake), it fails with below error:

```
configure: exit 1
debian/rules:161: recipe for target 'config.status' failed
make: *** [config.status] Error 1
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
```

I am not able to figure out what is wrong here. The error is a generic error.
If I run `./configure`, `make`, then build goes fine.

Here are relevant lines from `debian/rules`

```
160 config.status: configure
161         dh_testdir
162
163         PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$(CURDIR)/debian/pkgconfig:$$PKG_CONFIG_PATH" \
164         ./configure $(confflags) CPPFLAGS="$(CPPFLAGS)" CFLAGS="$(CFLAGS)" LDFLAGS="$(LDFLAGS)" \
165                 JAVAC="$(JAVAC)" JAR="$(JAR)" JAVA_CPPFLAGS="$(JAVA_CPPFLAGS)" \
166                 JAVA_LDFLAGS="$(JAVA_LDFLAGS)" \
167                 || ( status=$$?; cat config.log; exit $$status )
```

Can you help with any pointers on what could be going wrong here? OR Any suggestion to make it provide *detailed error* would be helpful because 
`configure: exit 1` does not give much insight to act upon.

BTW, I have `export DH_VERBOSE=1` enabled in `debian/rules`.

**UPDATE:**

As suggested by @GiacomoCatenazzi:

- Yes, I can run `dh_testdir` successfully.
- I ran `make` with `debian/rules` as makefile and verbose enabled as `make -d -f debian/rules`. This time again it failed on the same `config.status` step with 2 more debug lines added which I could not understand.

Here are the last few lines of output of above `make` command:

```
...
...
...
#define HAVE_PLUGIN_VSERVER 1
#define HAVE_PLUGIN_WIRELESS 1
#define HAVE_PLUGIN_WRITE_GRAPHITE 1

configure: exit 1
Reaping losing child 0x1a103d0 PID 27476
debian/rules:161: recipe for target 'config.status' failed
make: *** [config.status] Error 1
Removing child 0x1a103d0 PID 27476 from chain.
```

- After running this, it created `config.log` which has about 30k lines.

Last few lines of the log are as below:

```
29303 #define HAVE_PLUGIN_WIRELESS 1
29304 #define HAVE_PLUGIN_WRITE_GRAPHITE 1
29305
29306 configure: exit 1
```

No helpful information here as well :(

**UPDATE:**

As suggested by @Stephen Kitt, The entire `config.log` is available here: http://pasted.co/3767a043

Comment: What it it the status of dh_testdir?  Could you run make using debian/rules as Makefile and config.status as target, and with verbose flag.

Comment: Could you post the complete `config.log` somewhere? It *will* have the cause of the error, but it can be hard to find.

Comment: Thanks for your time @Stephen. I have added the `config.log` to the thread.

Comment: The `exit 1` looks like it returns an error on purpose, and that you just don't notice when you run it interactively because you don't normally look at its exit code when you run something interactively.

Comment: Could you try building with `pdebuild` again and posting the build log? It’s stored in a file with extension `.build` in the source directory’s parent directory.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration failed for the following reason:

```
configure:59894: error: "Some plugins are missing dependencies - see the summary above for details"
```

The summary isn’t included in the logs but should have been output to your terminal.

You need to install a number of packages to satisfy `collect-pw`’s build dependencies.

The log file you’ve posted, which I think comes from your direct attempts using `debian/rules`, indicates that many dependencies are missing, of which at least some are listed in `debian/control` and would be installed by `pdebuild` (`pkg-config`, `libyajl-dev` and others). Since the build is failing with `pdebuild` too, I’m guessing there are dependencies specific to `collect-pw` which aren’t listed in `collectd`’s `debian/control`; you should investigate the missing build-dependencies and add them to `debian/control` (and install them locally if you want to build locally).

Comment: This information gives me few things to look at and try it. I will post my outcome as I get to it. Thanks.

Comment: It's been more than 5 days (since this thread, 2 weeks overall) and I am still struggling to fix the missing dependancies issue. I tried to customize `configure`, disable plug-ins.. and quite a few other things (by virtue of reverse engineering the code) which I could think of. I've spent more time than necessary on this and hence giving up. I really appreciate your inputs as it helped me explore how the gnu `automake`, `autoconf` work and learned a lot of theory along the way. Thanks.